# UK visa for two different interview

Tags: uk

I have interview invitations from two different company in the UK which I should need to visit the UK. Today I got the first invitation letter to start the visa process from the first company while the second one will be ready in a few days. I wonder if can I take multi-entry standard visitor visa with this situation? Or do I have to reapply with the second invitation letter while visa processing of the first invitation will be in progress? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: UK visas are visit visas are typically multiple entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be issued a Standard UK Visitor Visa Type C which will be most probably Multiple Entry you can appear for multiple interviews with different companies BUT make sure you do not conduct any activity which involves the payment against your services/involvement as this will violates the Standard Visitor Visa Condition.